# Upload to random named directories, is it enough (security-wise)?

Tags: php, security, file-upload, filesystems

So I've built a form that lets users to upload files (within an extensions whitelist) to random-named directories, under another directory in root. The random name, for tech reasons, for now it's written down in the html page, but visible in code only while the page exists. If the user refreshes the page, the name will change. Only the random dir name itself is visible, not the entire upload  in itpath.

```
data-name="<?php echo uniqidReal(); ?>" // outputs like 'd91806dbde743568'
```

That name is then used by php to create the dir where the files will be saved, something like `https://www.acme.com/mydir/d91806dbde743568/file.mp3`. That entire url will be then send once to the receiver of the form.

The 'mydir' contents are under `-Indexes`, so no way for anyone to guess the name of the random named dirs in it.

Now my question: is that enough to avoid security issues? Could one, for example, upload a masked file that contains some malicious code that once uploaded can read the dirs and send them back informations or do something else?

Should I strengthen the security level in some other way?

Comment: why do you need the directory being created before the upload?

Comment: To avoid file collisions.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best way, because the name of a folder can have characters like ../

It seems to me better to create a random folder on the server without receiving data from the user

Comment: Mmm, but the name is not based on user's input in my case. It's generated by a specific function that uses a combination of `random_bytes` + `microtime`

Comment: user can change this field

Comment: Mmm, how? It's not a field.

Comment: In Chrome DevTools. Yes, its attribute.

Comment: Ok yes. No it's not a field, that data is applied to a div, but yes you can change it via console, I didn't thought about it, good point.